# Laptop keyboard stops working soon after boot

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have a Benq Joybook 5000 which is coming up for 6 years old now.  It will boot fine but after between 1 and 5 minutes after boot the keyboard will stop functioning along with the mouse pad and all other buttons.  The only way to switch it off once this has happened is to hold down the power button.

Once i've done this then the laptop will refuse to boot, the BIOS doesn't even start up but the lights and fan come on.  If the laptop is left for an hour or so then it will again boot but the keyboard issue returns as above.

EDIT 01-10-09

After trying out a few of the suggestions below it would seem that the problem is hardware related.  I've done a memory test using Memtest which passed OK.  I've now booted from a Linux live cd, then opened up a word processor to leave the cursor flashing in an empty document.  After 5 minutes the keyboard and mousepad etc stopped working again, same problem as in Windows but the computer itself has not crashed or locked up, the cursor is still flashing in the document.  The computer seems fine in all other respects apart from the fact that the keyboard and mousepad stop working.

I've also plugged in a USB mouse after the keyboard and mousepad have stopped functioning and it worked fine.

Any suggestions further to this would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

If it lockups up and only starts working after leaving it for a while, it sounds like it is over-heating.

If you go into the bios, does it have an option to show you the cpu temperature and fan speed. Also if you leave it in the bios for about five minutes does it lock up?

Comment: I would say this is the most likely cause. Open up the laptop and verify if the fan is still functional and the vents are not blocked by dust bunnies...

Comment: I don't think it is overheating now since I've left it overnight and it won't boot at all now.  The lights and fan come on but it seems the BIOS never kicks in and the screen just stays blank and it does nothing.  What could be the cause of this?  I've heard that the BIOS will still POST even if the battery is flat?

Comment: Also, it's not actually locking up, the computer still runs fine it's just that the keyboard and mousepad etc stop working.

Answer (score 0):

not much to go on, but here's a couple of things to try..

- try an external mouse / keyboard. same issue?
- try a live boot CD.. e.g. xp install cd, ubuntu. do you see the same issue if you leave the device on for a while?
- has the bios battery gone flat? try replacing it?
- search the manufacturer's website for bios and firmware updates for the laptop

Comment: Tried a Linux live cd and the issue was the same, the computer doesn't lock just the keyboard and mousepad stop working.  After the keyboard and mousepad stopped working I plugged in a USB mouse which worked fine.